# How to draw an image with a transformation to another image with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What is the easiest / simplest / performant way to draw an image to an existing image but applying a transformation (described with a matrix) ?

What I would like to do is having a canvas, and draw many small images on it using 2D affine transformation matrices for each of these images.

Comment: Was there a particular problem with your current code?

Comment: I just have no idea on how to do it with PIL... With opencv, there is `warpAffine()` that takes an output image on which the image is drawn, but with PIL, the only function that does transform is `.transform`, but it generates a new image instead of letting the possibility to pass an existing one... Plus google is not really my frined on that one (or maybe I don't use the right keywords)

Comment: So you can generate a new image and draw it on top of another one.

Comment: WITH OPENCV. However for this project, we use PIL, and we can't add opencv as a dependency

Comment: Yes. You said you can transform an image and get a new image. Now you can use the new image and draw it on top of the background image.

Comment: Ok, but 1) im.transform needs a size parameter. 2) the bigger image has black background, thus pasting on the other won't work 3) probably need to have a mask... 4) do you call it "simple" ?
I just hoped such a common task would have some shortcuts...